# fetching 2nd element from file?

Tags: bash, ksh

This is how my table.txt looks like:

```
name        text
test123     rock
test345     cena
```

I am going to use table information in my a.sh file, which looks like the following:

```
e = 345
echo "the value of e is $e"
a=$(awk -v str=test '$2 ~ "^" $e { print $2 ; exit;}' /desktop/table.txt)
if [ -z "$a" ]
   then echo "string not found: $arr"
   else echo "String found: $arr"
fi
```

Expected output cena.

How:   when it goes to arr -> test345   and will print out second element which is cena.

Error:
String not found:

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write this:

```
awk -v regex="^test$e" '$1 ~ regex { print $2 ; exit;}'
```

- construct the regex outside the awk body
- compare against $1, not $2

Do you want to do a string equality test instead of regex matching?

```
awk -v str="test$e" '$1 == str { print $2 ; exit;}'
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed and it makes sense. gold :)